# Mercurial revert/backout a single file

Tags: mercurial

In Mercurial I have an old changeset which is all good apart from the alterations to a single file.  How would I revert the alterations to that single file?

Even just being able to view the state of the file at the previous changeset would be good then I could cut & paste.

My Mercurial client is TortoiseHg.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As of TortoiseHg 2.8.1

1. Commit in case something goes wrong
2. Right click the revision you want to roll back to, select Browse At Revision
3. Find the file you want to revert to this revision, right click, 'Revert to this revision (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>)
4. Repeat 3 for all files you want to revert

Answer (score 12):

Raghuram's answer is no longer correct due to stylistic(~) changes to TortoiseHG.  "*Repository Browser*" has been renamed "*TortoiseHG Workbench*", but, more importantly, "*Revert file contents*"  is no longer an action on the context menu.

As of version 2.0.4, you'll want to:

1. Commit your current repository in case something goes wrong.
2. Open the relevant changeset in "*TortoiseHG Explorer*"
3. In the file listing, right-click on the file you which to revert.
4. Select "*Revert to Revision*" from the context menu.
5. You'll be presented with a confirmation dialog that contains a checkbox labeled "*Revert all files to this revision*".  Make sure that it's unchecked.
6. Hit "*OK*".
7. Verify that only that file was reverted.  If everything was reverted, update to the revision created in step 1.

The first time I tried this, I'm not sure what I did wrong, but I reverted the whole repository instead of the single file.  So, definitely make sure you commit a new revision before trying it.

Comment: It reverts to this revision, but doesn't revert the change in the revision itself. Very inconvenient.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're looking for.  Maybe you're wanting to revert to the revision before that?

Comment: Yes, I want to revert half of some commit, say, several files. This means that I want to revert them to revisions that they had before this commit. So I have to look in each file's history, find revision before my commit and revert it separately. 10 files and you hate HG.

Comment: If you want to make a separate question I'll answer it. ;)

Comment: Yeah, this didn't work well for me. I think the interface has changed some, but I managed to revert the whole codebase even though it said it was only for one file.

Answer (score 7):

Open `Repository Browser`, go to the interested changeset.  You will see a list of changed files.  Choose the file you are intersted and Click on `Revert file contents`

Answer (score 7):

CLI-version, applicable to any (fresh) version of TortoiseHG

In order to undo changes only in FILE, introduced in changeset CSET, use this form of backout

`hg backout -r CSET --include FILE`

Comment: I'm not sure this would do what I want.  I think this would revert alterations for a file in a specific changeset.  I'd like to revert a file back to exactly how it was in a specific changeset, ignoring all subsequent changsets.

Comment: This is the actual answer, equivalent to "backout" on a changeset but just for one file. Revert to revision is a much more drastic thing. Strange that TortoiseHg has two different things for changeset vs file revision

Answer (score 2):

I've discovered the answer to the second part at least.  To view the contents of a single file at an old revision do the following in TortoiseHg:

1. Right click on the file and select repository explorer.
2. Click on the revision you'd like to revert back to.
3. Right click on the file in the bottom left pane.  Select either view at revision or save at revison.

Answer (score 1):

To view an old version of a file using TortoiseHg (as of version 2.2.1), open TortoiseHG Workbench, right click on an old rev, and click "Browse at rev..."

Answer (score 1):

While the recommendation to use TortoiseHg's `Browse at rev...` will help you see what got changed (i.e. what you might want to back out), it won't help you back out the file--if, as more than one answer suggests, you choose `Revert to Revision`, you will only be backing out *subsequent* changes, not the change in the changeset.

The easiest way to undo a changeset for a single file (at least, as of TortoiseHg 2.6.1):

1. Browse to the file in Windows explorer, and select it
2. Right-click, and from the TortoiseHg context submenu, choose `Revision History`
3. Select the revision *prior to* the one you're trying to back out
4. Right-click, and choose `Revert to Revision`
5. Make sure the "Revert all files to this revision" checkbox is unchecked (it will
   be by default after following these steps)

Of course, if by "old changeset" you mean there are subsequent changes to that file that you want to keep, there is no way to do that except to examine the changeset and manually undo the changes.